# How to animate a paper being cut by scissors

Tags: animation

I need help trying to make an animation of paper being cut by scissors. The paper pieces should fall off as they're being cut. :)
[image: like this:]

Comment: Hello it's not clear what the animation is supposed to be from this picture, could you please show a storyboard?

Comment: dont look at the image it doesnt matter at all.

Comment: at least you should add a link to an animation how it should look like and delete the obvious superfluous image in your question if it doesn't help at all. thx.

Comment: like this but after its cut it should just fall down (boh pieces)

Comment: Er ... If we're supposed to ignore the image, why is it there? We need to know whether this is, say, a ribbon being cut and falling away, or a sheet being cut and flopping where split, but intact otherwise.. (some/all of us will cheat :) .. we have to know what we can get away with)  Please clue us in. Thanks

Comment: it was the old image that was supposed to be ignored. it just needs to be a paper being cut in half or anything really..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a plane, subdivide it, assign a vertex group to all its vertices, rip its central edge (where it is supposed to be cut, press <kbd>V</kbd>), give it *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier and a *Cloth* simulation, in the *Physics > Cloth* panel choose the vertex group as *Pin Group* under *Shape*:

[image]

Create an object that will be the cutter object and that needs to look something like this:

[image]

In the *Vertex Weight Proximity* of the plane select the cutter object as *Target Object, Proximity Mode > Geometry, Geometry > Face*, so that the cutter object will now be able to move the pin group. You'll tweak the *Lowest* and *Highest* value:

[image]

Result when you animate the cutter object (make it invisible):

[image]

Some more tweakings  if I want it to look more like your picture (positive *Gravity*, more *Air Visquosity* for the cloth, a *Force Field > Force* in order to spread the 2 pieces a bit more):

[image]